# Zap export report is not working in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-plugins, zap

Trying to export report using ZAP in Jenkins.
Getting below errors :-

[ZAP Jenkins Plugin] INITIALIZATION [ SUCCESSFUL ]

```
REQUIRED PLUGIN(S) ARE MISSING
```

[ZAP Jenkins Plugin] SHUTDOWN [ START ]

and  in local OWASP ZAP/zap.log:-
2018-11-18 09:52:48,551 [main ] INFO  Options ParamCertificate - Unsafe SSL renegotiation disabled.2018-11-18 09:52:49,684 [main ] INFO  ENGINE - open start - state not modified 2018-11-18 09:52:50,085 [main ] INFO  ENGINE - dataFileCache open start2018-11-18 09:52:50,134 [main ] INFO  ENGINE - dataFileCache open end2018-11-18 09:52:50,498 [ZAP-daemon] INFO  ExtensionFactory - Loading extensions2018-11-18 09:52:50,746 [ZAP-daemon] ERROR ExtensionAutoUpdate - Unable to load the configuration org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException: Unable to load the configuration

Comment: Install the required plugins...

Comment: I have installed OWASP ZAP Jenkins plugin,OWASP Dependency Check plugin, OWASP Dependency track, OWASP Zap plugin.

Comment: Ok first off Zap and Dependency Check/Track are completely different products/projects. Second Zap is complaining about it's plugins. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/zaproxy-jenkins is probably your best source for support.

Comment: Thank you . I will follow above link.

Comment: Issue got resolved.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know, could you answer your own question for the next person (or provide a link to the thread)?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue:- Added add-on **exportreport-alpha-5 plugin** in the ZAP Home directory (in plugin directory) .